# Redirecting ls command to file dose not produce the same result

Tags: format, output, ls

```
ls dir
```

screen result:

```
file_a file_b file_c
```

but

```
ls dir > ls.txt
```

ls.txt content:

```
file_a
file_b
file_c
```

**why?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ls dir:** List the files in the working directory. [[1](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0030.php)]

**ls dir > ls.txt:** Most command line programs that display their results do so by sending their results to a facility called standard output. By default, standard output directs its contents to the display. To redirect standard output to a file, the ">" character is used. In this example, the ls command is executed and the results are written in a file named ls.txt. Since the output of ls was redirected to the file, no results appear on the display.[[2](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0070.php)]

The result of `ls dir` is written in short format this is why it appears in one line. `ls dir > ls.txt` however writes each folder/file name in a separate line of the text file.

If you would like to print the result of ls dir in that format you can use the long format `ls dir -l`.

Comment: It seems that:
 ls dir > ls.txt    actually equals    ls -1 dir > ls.txt 
It means when redirecting , ls stealthily adds a  -1 parameter ?